# How does python contextmanager reraise an exception back into the decorated generator?

Tags: python, exception, generator, yield, contextmanager

This is a question about how `contextmanager` does what it does.

`contextmanger` is a decorator that calls the decorated function (a generator) twice, in order to build the `__enter__` and `__exit__` functions, to be consumed by the `with` clause, so far so good. What I do not understand is -- when an exception is raised *inside the `with` block*, how come an `except` block *inside the generator* can catch it?

```
@contextmanager
def f():
    try:
        yield 'foo'
    except Exception as e:
        print('How can I ever reach here??')
        print(e)
    finally:
        print('finally')

with f() as p:
    print(p)
    raise Exception('bar')
```

output is

```
foo
How can I ever reach here??
bar
finally
```

I think the magic happens in the `@contextmanager`, becuase if I remove the decorator, and just do a 'yield inside try block', the exception outside the generator is not caught inside the generator:

```
def f():
    try:
        yield 'foo'
    except Exception as e:
        print('How can I ever reach here??')
        print(e)
    finally:
        print('finally')

g = f()
print(next(g))
raise Exception('bar')
```

output is

```
foo
Traceback (most recent call last):
...
Exception: bar
```

I looked into the `contextlib.contextmanager` code but still couldn't figure out how this is even possible using pure python code. Something fundamental about the language I missed here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic that's confusing you is in `_GeneratorContextManager`.  Your function `f` is self.gen.  The code has just called `next(self.gen)`, gotten back the string `"foo"`, and is waiting.  `f()` is sitting in the middle of the `yield` statement.

At this point you throw an exception.  Since python sees you are inside a `with` block, (and these are built into the language), it calls the `__exit__` method of the generator with arguments describing the error.  This is they way context managers work.  The context manager calls `self.gen.throw` which resumes the generator by throwing that exception. into it.  Voila.  You are in the exception handler.

Does this make it clearer?

Comment: "with `type` as the type of error and `value` being None" - what? No, the value is the exception object, not `None`.

Comment: You are right.  I'm confusing it with a different construct.  But I got the flow correct.  Will correct.  Thanks.

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you. Your answer leads me to [PEP 342](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/#new-generator-method-throw-type-value-none-traceback-none), which adds a .throw() method. This .throw() can inject an exception back into a generator, which is added into native python, and that's exactly what I missed.

Comment: btw, in your answer, function `foo` should be function `f`, as there is only function `f` and string `'foo'`

Comment: @QnA.  Thanks.  Fixed.